# Toolbar in main VC and Toolbar in Modal VC won't show same button

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, modal-dialog, toolbar

I am running into a weird issue that I can't find anything for on the internet. I have a UIViewController that is showing a toolbar at the bottom with a custom button in it. That button is added like..

```
List<UIBarButtonItem> items = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();

UIButton _helpButton = new UIButton();
//....
// code to create our custom button with background
// .....

UIBarButtonItem helpBarButton = new UIBarButtonItem(_helpButton);
items.Add(helpBarButton);
```

When showing our VC, we show the toolbar and everything looks great. On the VC, we have a button that opens another VC(as the root view of another UINavigationController) as a modal FormSheet. In `ViewDidAppear`, we also set the toolbar to visible, which would show the same help button, which also works great.

Once the modal VC is shown, since it's not full screen, you can still see the other VC in the background. The toolbar on the background VC no longer has the help button visible(the Toolbar is still showing). There is no code that removes or hides the help button, so I'm not sure what is happening to it.

As I don't really know how to set this scenario up in objective-c, I'm not sure if this is an iOS issue, a Xamarin.iOS issue, or an issue with my understanding of the toolbar.

Also, if I don't show the toolbar in the modal VC, the background VC's Toolbar keeps the help button. This is what I don't understand, as the background VC is shown by one UINavigationController, and the modal VC is shown by a different UINavigationController. Why would doing something with one Toolbar effect the other Toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're adding the very **same** button to the modal VC, when you add the button to the second toolbar it will call `AddSubView` sometime which will call `RemoveFromSuperView` before actually adding the button into the toolbar.

`UIView`s may have only **one** SuperView.

Comment: Ahh....I didn't know a UIView could only be in one SuperView and that it would be removed from other super views.  Thanks.